# 循環してしまう木構造をGoroutineで処理したい。

Tags: go

いま木構造でそれぞれのノードでGoroutineを作成し、ある処理を行い更に下位のノードのGoroutineをそのGoroutineで起動するようなプログラムを作成しています。そこで問題は、あるノードの下に、これまでに別のGoroutineで辿ったノードが出てきてしまう場合です。同じノードのしたには100%同じ木構造が構築される状況なので、そのすでに辿ったノードの下にはすでに別のGoroutineにより辿ったノードがあるので、無駄な処理になってしまいます。
そこで、すでに調べたノードを記憶して後からそのノード以下を辿らないようにしたいです。この場合スライスを用いて、すでに辿ったノードの識別子を登録し、それぞれのGoroutineで参照し、一致しなければ下位ノードのGoroutineを起動するようにしましたがこれがうまくできません。この場合はどのような方法が考えられますか。

以下に検証に用いたサンプルプログラムを示します。

```
package main

import "math/rand"
import "time"
import "fmt"

var alpha =[]string{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"}

func main() {
    c := make(chan string)
    s := make([]string, 0, len(alpha))
    for i:=0; i<3; i++{
        go routine(s, c)
    }

    for{
        res := <-c
        s = append(s, res)
        if len(s) == len(alpha){
            break
        }
    }

    for _, v := range s{
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}

func routine(s []string, ch chan string){
    c := random()
    for _,v := range s{
        if v == c{
            return
        }
    }
    ch <- c
    for i:=0;i<3;i++{
        go routine(s,ch)
    }
}

func random()string{
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    return alpha[rand.Intn(len(alpha))]
}
```

**結果**

```
C
H
M
I
L
D
L
F
I
I
K
K
H
```

ここでは対象のデータは木構造になっていないです。
このようにすでに出てきたものもスライスに保存されてしまいます。さらに実際に作成しようとしているコードでは、木構造全体のノード数(ここではABC...)が未知数なので、Sliceを用いた方法はできないと考えられます(capなしのappendは新しいアドレスを確保するため)。

この場合どのようにして、すでに辿ったノードを判断すればいいのでしょうか。

Comment: まずはgoroutineを使わずに、循環するノードを省いてたどる方法を考え、それからgoroutineを使って並列化することを考えるのが良いですよ。

Comment: サンプルプログラムに限って言えば、スライスのポインタを渡せば良いのではないでしょうか。`go routine(&s, c)`,  `func routine(s *([]string), ch chan string) {...}`, `for _, v := range *s {...}` ですが、木構造全体のノード数が未知数ということですので、スライスを使う場合には cap を十分に大きく設定するしかなさそうですね。それと、関係はありませんが、サンプルプログラムでスライスポインタを使う場合、channel の読み出し部分で dead lock が発生する場合があります。3 個の goroutine 全てが既出の文字列を選んでしまう場合です。

Comment: 「循環する木構造」というのは定義からして矛盾する気がするのですが… 無向グラフの全ノードを非重複走査したいというのが目的でしょうか。

Comment: @KoRoN
アドバイスありがとう御座います。考えてみます。

Comment: @argus
それについては、スライスを内包した構造体を作り、それを通じてアクセスするというのはどうでしょうか。これでも、2番めの問題は解決できそうにありませんが。

Comment: @yohjp
すみません。自分でも調べましたが、木構造は循環しないものをいうのでした。
おそらく、有向グラフだと思います。

Comment: 実際のプログラムで有効かどうかはわかりませんが、サンプルコードを書き換えてみました。具体的にはスライスではなくマップを使うのと、deadlock の問題は残りの分だけ goroutine を起動する様に変更してみました。[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LmB1p7Wy4b) にコードを置いたのですが、playground 上では「process took too long」となってしまい実行できませんので、ローカルにコピーして試してみて下さい。# map は concurrent read/write ができないので map へのアクセスはメインスレッド内だけにしました

Comment: @argus
ありがとう御座います。試してみます。